# Working with conditions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

How do I properly use @if in this situation?

It always tells me `expected ;` but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(item.Client.Surname + ", " + item.Client.FirstName, "Details", "Assessments", new { id = item.ClientID }, null)
        </td>
        <td>
            @if (item.Doctor.Surname != null)
            {
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Doctor.Surname) , @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Doctor.FirstName)
            } //here -- ; expected-- i tried adding ; but it doesn't work

        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReferFor)
        </td>
}
```

What I want to happen is when `Doctor.Surname` is null, it will leave a blank `<td>`

Comment: At which line it says - expected ;

Comment: @Yogi I edited my post so you can see which line

Comment: Wrap the comma in a `<span>`- `@Html.DisplayFor(..)<span>,</span>`@Html.DisplayFor(..)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it using a span for example:

```
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.Client.Surname + ", " + item.Client.FirstName, "Details", "Assessments", new { id = item.ClientID }, null)
            </td>
            <td>
                @if (item.Doctor.Surname != null)
                {
                    <span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Doctor.Surname) , @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Doctor.FirstName)</span>
                }
                else
                {
                    <span>&nbsp;</span>
                }

            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReferFor)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following line -

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Doctor.Surname) , @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Doctor.FirstName)
```

in this line, `,` is used in line, which is causing the error.

You should use `@Html.Raw(" , ")` instead. So the statement would become -

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Doctor.Surname) @Html.Raw(" , ") @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Doctor.FirstName)
```

Comment: I tried and seems it will work, but unfortunately I got a new error

Comment: A `<label>` is not an appropriate html element. Make it a `<span>` or use `@Html.Raw(" , ")`

Comment: int this line `@if (item.Doctor.Surname != null)`, it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Can you help me with this too? I know it is not included in my post.

Comment: It means `Doctor` is `null`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Thanks for your comments. Updated my ans. :)

Comment: @kielou - As said by stephen, the object `Doctor` is null. Make sure you build your model object properly and pass it to view correctly.

Comment: @StephenMuecke that gave me the idea how to solve it.. thanks to both of you